# How to increase the MYSQL table space in centos

Tags: mysql, centos

I have installed MYSQL under Centos server and i want to increase the space of the table but i can't do this. Please anyone help me to do this..

Comment: I try to increase the table space.

Comment: what do you mean by 'i want to increase the space of the table' ?

Answer (score 0):

Table space you mean size of table to store data? there is no limit it will grow as data inserted upto your hardisk size limit